# In order traversal BST in python?

Tags: python, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, inorder

There's a question on LeetCode involving the summation of all tree node values which fall between supplied left and right parameters. The top python solution used the following code

```py
class TreeNode(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None 

class Solution(object):
    def rangeSumBST(self, root, L, R):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :type L: int
        :type R: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        return self.inorder(root, 0, L, R)

    def inorder(self, root, value, L, R):
        if root:
            print(root.val) # I added this to say what came of it. 
            value = self.inorder(root.left, value, L, R)
            if root.val >= L and root.val <= R:
                value += root.val
            value = self.inorder(root.right, value, L, R)

        return value
```

The test case looks like this:

```
       10
      /  \
     5    15
    / \    \
   3   7   18
```

The order the nodes were visited is as follows:
`10,5,3,7,15,18` and the print statement verified this.

The summation returned was 32 because it included the elements `10,7,15`.

Where I am confused is - in this code, I do not see the root variable being updated anywhere in the code, yet it appears to be doing so. I understand it's using in-order traversal, but I'm lost as to how this code elicits this effect.

Source: https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/discuss/193235/Python3-or-Easy-to-understand-or-InOrder-Traversal

Comment: It's a recursive method; it doesn't "update" `root`, but it does call itself recursively with different values for the `root` argument. It will probably help to step through the code using e.g. http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: @kaya3, Oh I see now.. If the user had any other variable name, `node` for example, I think it would have clicked. I'm used to seeing a root attribute as part of BST classes. And so, when I looked at it, I was confused because it appeared to be calling the children of the same node repeatedly. I think I get it now.